# manually do a `make install`

Tags: 12.04, installation

I just built a large program that had some other programs in the source tree.

`make install` just installed the main program, but I want to install all of the sub-programs that were built as well.

Is there a way to do this?

**Note:** by install I mean that I can type it from any shell, or through any program (though really I only care about make) and it will run.

Comment: This might depend on the program. What are you trying to install?

Comment: @strugee In this particular case, it is `scan-build` and `scan-view` tools from clang, but it could be anything. I am assuming that I know the files that have to be added

Answer (score 1):

What the `make install` command does depends on how the Makefile is written and what it consists.

The most generic way of finding out what binaries, libraries, man pages, etc. your `make` command produces so that you can modify your Makefile could be like the one below. I assume you're in the top of your build directory.

```
touch /tmp/tstamp
make clean
./configure [your options]
make
find . -newer /tmp/tstamp
```

This should give you a list of files that have been modified since you've created the /tmp/tstamp file.

Compare the list of files being installed with `make install` with the list  obtained by using the `find` command and add the desired remaining files to your Makefile.

If you get that list and just want to make it work (in a quick and dirty manner), moving them to proper target locations should be a matter of a simple for loop one-liner, bearing in mind the --prefix (if any) you've specified during the build configuration stage.

Comment: In this case, the makefile is far too long and complex to read (the program happens to be something that is built as part of clang). I know the files that need to be added to the path, or whatever they need to be added to, but I don't know where to do that

Comment: I'd probably find the 'install' target of that Makefile or if you can't/don't want to do it, but wanted to do it cleanly, I'd recommend packaging it into a deb.

Comment: I think my problem is more basic (though this is very helpful in other cases). I have a list of files that need to be moved. I just don't know where I should move them to.

Comment: I think I understand. Usually when you run `configure --help` it shows you the default `prefix` (the root of the filesystem hierarchy your package will be configured with - for distribution packages it's usually '/', for user built packages, it's often '/usr/local/').

You usually move the files produced during the `make` step somewhere beneath the prefix into <prefix>/lib, <prefix>/etc/, <prefix>/usr/share/man, etc.

Some packages when you build them (make) leave the output in the relative directories, i.e. ./usr/bin/<app> ./usr/share/man, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not always so - many times you're just left with a bunch of files generated in seemingly random subdirectories of the build directory. In such cases aside from man pages, configuration files and binaries which are usually easy, you'll need to experiment a bit to figure out for instance where does your binary expect to find the required library. `ldd /path/to/binary` can often help, unless the binary is statically built but it's a bit of manual work.